# passing a list from org spreadsheet to lisp function

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I have a table named TABLE1 and I am trying to pass a list to the function `foo` as follow:

```
#+TBLFM: $1='(foo list(a b c))

(defun foo (my-list) 
  (first my-list)
)
```

Unfortunately the table formula evaluates to #ERROR. Any idea how I can go about passing a list to the function?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a valid function for it to work.  `(foo list(a b c))` fails to evaluate even in the `*scratch*` buffer.

If you change the formula to:

```
(foo (list "a" "b" "c"))
or
(foo (list 'a 'b 'c))
or
(foo '(a b c))
```

it will return `a` in the table field.